# "Last modified" timestamp corruption

Tags: filesystem, samba

On my DIY NAS (Ubuntu 22.04.2 LTS, Samba Version 4.15.13-Ubuntu) working among other things as a file server for Windows clients I'm facing a rather weird issue.

The "last modified" timestamp for some random files get set to `0x80000000`:

```
pwsh> stat /data/P/Photos/2022/07/11/_MG_9662.jpg
File: /data/P/Photos/2022/07/11/_MG_9662.jpg
Size: 9409475 Blocks: 18384 IO Block: 4096 regular file
Device: 10300h/66304d Inode: 233443606 Links: 1
Access: (0764/-rwxrw-r--) Uid: ( 1000/ sto) Gid: ( 1000/ sto)
Access: 2023-03-01 17:15:10.470901300 +0100
Modify: 1901-12-13 20:55:13.000000000 +0009
Change: 2023-03-01 17:39:59.215467666 +0100
Birth: 2022-07-17 21:00:34.495834896 +0200
pwsh> stat -c %Y /data/P/Photos/2022/07/11/_MG_9662.jpg
-2147483648
pwsh> "0x{0:X8}" -f -2147483648
0x80000000
```

How would you investigate that issue?

Filesystem bug?

Samba bug?

Windows bug?

Answer (score 0):

I've tracked down the issue to the FFC tool from [Uwe Sieber's excellent collection of free tools](https://www.uwe-sieber.de/filetools_e.html) that I use to compare files. I'll be working with Uwe to get a fix.